# Java generics - override a function that returns a set<T>

Tags: java, generics

This works :

```
public interface A {
     A doSomething(); 
}

public interface B extends A{
     B doSomething(); 
}
```

This doesn't :

```
public interface A {
     Collection<A> doSomething(); 
}

public interface B extends A{
     Collection<B> doSomething(); 
}
```

Why? and what can I do to get the functionality I want in the second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public interface A {
    Collection<? extends A> doSomething();
}

public interface B extends A{
    Collection<B> doSomething(); 
}
```

and it'll work properly.

It's because "a collection of B" does not extend a collection of A", even though B extends A. A needs to define the return type as a "collection of items that extends A" than you can narrow it further as "a collection of B". Confusing, yes ... but that's just how it is.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that `Collection<B>` is *not a sub-type of* `Collection<A>`.

Not every operation that's possible with a `Collection<A>` is also possible with a `Collection<B>`. Case in point: calling `add(new A())` works with a `Collection<A>` but *must* fail with a `Collection<B>` (even if that's just checked at compile-time).

If you don't care about *adding* elements to the returned `Collection` (often you only care about iterating over them, effectively treating them as if they were read-only), then you can do this:

```
public interface A {
     Collection<? extends A> doSomething();
}

public interface B extends A{
     Collection<? extends B> doSomething();
}
```

You can even let `B.doSomething()` return a `Collection<B>` if you want, but then you won't be able to extend `B` in the same way again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public interface A {
     Collection<? extends A> doSomething(); }
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html